# How to include a tex file with own formatting options

Tags: formatting, tex-core, include

I have two tex files, `tex1` and `tex2`. I want to include `tex1` into `tex2`. I know `\include` and `\input` but those won't allow to include tex files with own formatting. `tex1` has a header for example but `tex2` doesn't, `documentclass` and used packages are also different. When I simply copy the content of `tex1` into `tex2` it will format with my formatting options but I want to keep those of `tex1`.

Is there an environment that will let me change formatting options inside but won't affect anything that is outside?

Comment: what do you mean by "formatting"? page style, page margins, ...?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Hi. Documentclass, packages, textwidth etc. are different in tex1. Sorry for my english maybe I used the wrong word.

Comment: It sounds as if you want to combined two documents which have different class options set without having to alter the settings part-way through. Depending on the detail of the problem, I'd either consider using the `combine` class or combining the typeset PDFs for example using `pdfpages`. A bit more detail would help work out which route you are after.

Comment: Thank you Joseph. Putting pdfs together won't work with numbering the pages. Best would be an environment in which I can temporarily change settings like \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{105pt}
I could remove the documentclass and all packages that are needed could be added to tex2.

Comment: Changing the page dimensions and settings mid-document is possible, but difficult. IMO it will also be very hard to find and set each and every other setting and its value. Actually LaTeX tries to avoid changing the typesetting rules mid-document, because that's usually not a good style.

Comment: Tilman: Note that `pdfpages`, as suggested by @JosephWright,  also allows to add page numbers and headings from the main document. You need to clear the `pagecommand` setting for this. Also, have a closer look to the suggested `combine` package. It might be just what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Combining two documents which have different class options set can be done in a couple of ways. I'd either consider using the `combine` class or combining the typeset PDFs for example using `pdfpages`. It *is* possible to change page dimensions and settings mid-document, but this is tricky and LaTeX doesn't encourage it as it tends to be poor design. (A bit more detail would help work out which route you are after.)